# Block with image and text using Bulma CSS

Tags: css, bulma

I try to make this block image with text using Bulma CSS. I've tried a lot of things (relative, z-index, etc.) and I didn't succeed making something great for desktop or mobile. Every time, the text is overflowed or get outside the box. I can't set title character limit, so I try also to have a word-break at a second line if possible.

Here is a sample of what I'm looking for :

[image]

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="block_article" data-overlay>
   <img src="/static/img/{{ article.image }}" alt="" />
   <a href="/a/{{ article.slug }}.html"><span>{{ article.name }}</span></a>
</div>
```

And my current CSS (not working) :

```
.block_article {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
}

.block_article span {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50px;
    left: 5%; 
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Result :

[image]

Is there some tips for that kind of thing, or a Bulma extension for this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Perhaps you can set the image in the background and add padding to the inner content

Comment: That's a good idea, but I prefer to use a more "Bulma-way" :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Bulma, have a look at the .hero element: https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/hero/. This might be what you are looking for. As Viira mentioned, you could add your image to the background (using background-image).

Also, learning how to center things (https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks ! That's really better with Hero using background-image and line-height in CSS. I've tried to use : background-size: cover; but my image is always top-left centered, and background-position doesn't change things, maybe because I use a width and a height on my block. Is there a way to trick the system ?

Comment: Your background-image cannot overflow the size of the container it is applied to. You can create a new container and use that to only hold the background image. It would have to be set to position: absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; (so that it always takes the size of it's parent). Don't forget to add position:relative to that parent, and you will also have to fiddle around with the z-index to make it look right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final HTML and CSS for people who are in the same case. It's probably not perfect, but this is a good start...

```
<div class="hero block_article" style="background-image: url('/static/img/{{ article.image }}');">
    <span>{{ article.name }}</span>
</div>

.block_article {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    line-height: 230px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.block_article span {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Result :

[image]